# Enum variable is found to be null when not set that way

Tags: java, enums, null

Whenever I try to get a field from an enum, it always returns null.
I've set the value of it according to the enum constructor. It still comes out null.

```
public enum TeamType {
    RED("Red",ChatColor.RED,DyeColor.RED,Point.RED),
    BLUE("Blue",ChatColor.BLUE,DyeColor.BLUE,Point.BLUE);  //<----Set as Point.RED/BLUE



    private String name;
    private int crystalHealth = 50;
    private Point point;
    private int teamPoints;
    private ChatColor chatColor;
    private DyeColor dye;
    private HashSet<ArenaPlayer> playerList = new HashSet<>();
    private List<ArenaPlayer> queue = new ArrayList<ArenaPlayer>();
    private Location spawn;


    public Point getPoint()
    {
        if(point == null)
            System.out.println("WHY? for: " + this.toString()); //<---This always runs

        return point;
    }

    private TeamType(String name,ChatColor color,DyeColor dye,Point point1) {
        this.name = name;
        this.point = point1; // <--- My assignment
        this.dye = dye;
        this.chatColor = color;
    }
```

The Point enum class

```
public enum Point{
    RED(ChatColor.RED + "Red",TeamType.RED),
    BLUE(ChatColor.BLUE + "Blue",TeamType.BLUE),
    NEUTRAL(ChatColor.WHITE +"None",null);

    private String name;
    private TeamType teamOwned;
    private Point(String name,TeamType team) {
        this.name = name;
        teamOwned = team;
    }

    public TeamType getTeamOwned() {
        return teamOwned;
    }

     public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
```

There's obviously something that's happening outside of my knowledge of Java.
Could it possibly be that the Point Enum is not initialized yet when TeamType enum is. This could explain why it's null.

I need some help.

Comment: You have not initialised the field `point`, so no surprise.

Comment: `point` is initialized in the constructor? @Jagger

Comment: Can you show the code of `Point` class/enum? The code here seems fine, hence I suspect `Point.BLUE` itself might be pointing to `null`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Sure! I edited to add the `Point` enum class

Comment: Try adding calls to [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) in your TeamType constructor to ensure you are not passing in null values as arguments. One call for each of the four arguments.

Comment: You seem to have some circular dependency leading to `null` You might want to get rid of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I think the source of the problem is that you have a circular reference. `TeamType` has a `Point` reference and vice versa.

Suppose the `TeamType` enum class is initialized, then the enum constants are initialized as well. These refer to `Point`, which is in turn initialized. The classloader loads the `Point` class, but will not initialize `TeamType` again. At this point, properties you expect to be non-null are still null.

---

The [JLS § 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) defines this process.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a class called A which has class B’s Object. (in UML terms A HAS B). at the same time we class B is also composed of Object of class A (in UML terms B HAS A). obviously this represents circular dependency because while creating the object of A, the compiler must know the size of B... on the other hand while creating object of B, the compiler must know the size of A. this is something like egg vs. chicken problem...

to avoid such type of circular dependency you can use any proxy interface .

https://dzone.com/articles/tackling-circular-dependency